# PyQt5 - possible bug in QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtabwidget

In the following code i have created a QTabWidget with Qt Designer which has 6 pages.

After ui compile finished i write the following line of code in the exported py file:

```py
self.tabWidget.setTabVisible(5,False)
```

so i set the the last page of QTabWidget to be hidden.

The full py code is:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.6
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(149, 153)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_1.setObjectName("tab_1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_1, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.tab_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.tab_6 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_6.setObjectName("tab_6")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_6, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.tabWidget.setTabVisible(5,False)
        
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_1), _translate("Dialog", "1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Dialog", "2"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("Dialog", "3"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("Dialog", "4"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), _translate("Dialog", "5"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_6), _translate("Dialog", "6"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem with the execution of this code is that i cannot navigate to all the pages with displayed arrow keys in the corner of QTabWidget

[image]

If i remove the one line snippet code then i can normally navigate.

Is there any related bug i have to know?
How can i fix this error?

Os version: Linux chris-Inspiron-3847 5.4.0-110-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 14 19:46:19 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

PyQt5 version: 5.15.4

Note that if i resize the QDialog window then all visible page are display correctly.

Also note, that this error only oquered when i hide the **last** page.

I have one possible solution:

```py
self.tabWidget.update()
```

after page hide, but it didn't work :( .

Comment: Mh, it seems a bug indeed. Does the behavior change if the visibility is changed at runtime, with a timer or through any other means?

Comment: This problem actually presented after a button is clicked inside a QTableWidget, so yes at runtime.

Comment: @musicamante Can you test it with pyqt6 and post the results?

Comment: The pages are there: (`self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(4)` works), but then if i navigate to left side, then the same bug...

Comment: I'd suggest you to open a ticket in the Qt bug report system.

Answer (score 0):

```py
self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled(5,False)
# set the style sheet to hide the disabled tab
self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab::disabled {width: 0; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;} ")
```

with the above code:

1. You disable the desired tab
2. You hide the disabled tabs